# Chat server spitting out memory addresses. Not sure why

Tags: java, client-server, chat

I'm currently working on a threaded server that allows multiple clients to connect and send messages to each other via "/username message" format. The server runs and my client class is able to connect successfully and be asked for a username, but once I attempt to send a message instead of receiving the output "To [username]: message" I receive "To: [memory address]: [memory address]" which I am confused about as I have not tried to print any objects.

Additionally, nothing is displayed on the client that is supposed to be on the other end of the message. The way I am handling the client threads is with an ArrayList that they are added to after they are created and started. The way I am attempting to send the messages to the clients on the other end is with a method in the server class that iterates through the ArrayList of client threads and outputs the message to the one with the corresponding name.

In advance: I am aware that my parseUserName and parseMessage methods are less than nice, but I've opted to let them sit until I can deal with the bigger problems. For reference, here is my server class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class ThreadedChatServer 
{


    //private ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5679);
    private ServerSocket server;
    ArrayList<ClientThread> clientThreads;

    public ThreadedChatServer(ServerSocket s) 
    {
        server = s;
        clientThreads = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
    }


    public void openServer() throws IOException 
    {
        while(true) 
        {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("The server is connected to " + client.getInetAddress());

            // starts a thread for this client
            ClientThread c = new ClientThread(client, this);
            c.start();
            clientThreads.add(c);
        }
    }

    // Iterates through the clientThreads ArrayList and prints the given message
    // to the client whose name matches the "to" parameter.
    public void sendMessage(String from, String to, String m) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientThreads.size(); i++) 
        {
            if (clientThreads.get(i).getUserName() != from &&
                    clientThreads.get(i).getUserName() == to) 
            {
                clientThreads.get(i).toClient.println(m);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException 
    {
        new ThreadedChatServer(new ServerSocket(5679)).openServer();
    }

    public class ClientThread extends Thread
{
    private Socket s;
    private String name;
    private BufferedReader fromClient;
    private PrintWriter toClient;
    private ThreadedChatServer server;

    public ClientThread(Socket c, ThreadedChatServer tc) throws IOException 
    {
        s = c;
        name = null;
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        toClient = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        server = tc;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        String s = null;
        int size = 0;
        char[] c = null;





        try 
        {
            toClient.println("Enter a username: ");
            s = fromClient.readLine();
            name = s;

            // Accept/send messages from the user
            while ((s = fromClient.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                size = s.length();
                c = new char[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
                {
                    c[i] = s.charAt(size - i - 1);
                }
                String output = c.toString();
                String s2 = "To " + parseUserName(output) + ": "
                        + parseMessage(output);
                toClient.println(s2);
                server.sendMessage(this.name, parseUserName(output), 
                        parseMessage(output));

            }

            // Close the connection 
            fromClient.close();
            toClient.close();
            this.s.close();
            clientThreads.remove(c);
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public String getUserName() {return name;}

    public String parseUserName(String s) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
        String temp = in.next();
        if (temp.charAt(0) == '/') 
        {
            temp = temp.substring(1, temp.length());
            return temp;
        }

        return temp;

    }

    public String parseMessage(String s) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
        String temp = in.next();
        Boolean firstSpaceCheck = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (temp.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                temp = temp.substring(i + 1, temp.length());
                firstSpaceCheck = true;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you HAVE to have four different variables, of three different types, all called `s`?  This makes things VERY hard to follow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the memory address, its the output from [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) which takes the format

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

In this case it looks like `[C@15b7986` which tells you you're sending the output of the character array `Object` back to the client so the output is that returned by [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). Replace

```
String output = c.toString();
```

with

```
String output = new String(c);
```

Comment: Totally overlooked this, thanks! Now I can get on with trying to figure out why the message isn't making it to the recipient :P